# How to add word wrap to Select Tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have this select option
I want to achieve something like this.
[image]

I tried adding word wrap but still not working
[image]

```
<select style="width: 563px;" chosen-with-disabled="glAccounts" ng-model="dbAccount.select"
    ng-options="(debitAccount.name +'('+ debitAccount.glCode +')')
                        for debitAccount in glAccounts
                        track by debitAccount.id"
    ng-disabled="!enableAddDebitAccount"
    class="form-control">
<option class="displaynone" value="" disabled>{{'label.selectdebit' |
    translate}}
</option>
```

Comment: You need to post the HTML code here so that we can help you

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without seeing what's wrong with your code, right? There may be multiple reasons why this is happening. Depending on the situation the answer to this question may be different. Since you didn't post your code, people downvoted your question.

Comment: I edited and include the code.

Comment: That's much better. But pls use snippets and not paste the code just like it is.

Comment: Your images got deleted out of the question?

Comment: my bad i accidentally deleted the images

Comment: add white-space: pre-wrap; to the desired element

Comment: @c0dm1tu tried it but still not working

Comment: remove elipsis if it has and add important like  `white-space: .... !important!;` [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Basically you can't do much to style an option element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option which states: ' Styling the <option> element is highly limited. Options don't inherit the font set on the parent. In Firefox, only color and background-color can be set however in Chrome or Safari it's not possible to set any properties. You can find more details about styling in our guide to advanced form styling.' You may find you have to implement your own select/option system.

Answer (score 0):

you can try padding-right;word-break

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).